# undeclared identifier "idhttp1" in delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

I am trying to load an image from a URL in Delphi 2010.

I'm pretty new to Delphi and found this code but keep getting:

> undeclared identifier at idhttp1.get

Do I need to add something to the uses? Thanks

```
uses
  GIFImg;

procedure TForm1.btn1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  MS : TMemoryStream;
  GIf: TGIFImage;
begin
  MS := TMemoryStream.Create;
  GIf := TGIFImage.Create;
  try
    IdHTTP1.get('http://www.google.com/intl/en_ALL/images/logo.gif',MS);
    Ms.Seek(0,soFromBeginning);       
    Gif.LoadFromStream(MS);
    img1.Picture.Assign(GIF);

  finally
    FreeAndNil(GIF);
    FreeAndNil(MS);
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usage suggests that `IdHTTP1` is a component of type `TIdHTTP` that is placed on the design surface of your form. Likely that is the step that you have missed. Once you perform that step the code should compile.